# laravel-mongodb : How to add a foreign key to two existing collections?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using `laravel-mongodb`(https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to manipulate data in mongodb,

I have two collections in mongoDB,they are `books` and `categories`.

later I will import them into mysql,so I want to correlate them with a foreign key first.

getting them from mongodb:

```
public function getBooksAndCategories()
{
    $books = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('books')->get();
    $categories = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('categories')->get();
}
```

they look like this:

```
    $books = collect([
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'history book 1', 'category' => 'history'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'history book 2', 'category' => 'history'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'science book 1', 'category' => 'science'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'science book 2', 'category' => 'science'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'sociology book 1', 'category' => 'sociology'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'sociology book 2', 'category' => 'sociology'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'economics book 1', 'category' => 'economics'],
    ]);




    $categories = collect([
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'history'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'science'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'sociology'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'economics'],
    ]);
```

first,i need to add a `id` into `$categories`,the result is like this:

```
    $newCategories = collect([
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'history','id' => 1],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'science','id' => 2],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'sociology','id' => 3],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','category' => 'economics','id' => 4],
    ]);
```

second, I need to add a foreign key into collection `$books`,the result is like this:

```
    $newBooks = collect([
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'history book 1', 'category' => 'history','category_id' => 1],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'history book 2', 'category' => 'history','category_id' => 1],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'science book 1', 'category' => 'science','category_id' => 2],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'science book 2', 'category' => 'science','category_id' => 2],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'sociology book 1', 'category' => 'sociology','category_id' => 3],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'sociology book 2', 'category' => 'sociology','category_id' => 3],
        ['_id' => 'xxx','name' => 'economics book 1', 'category' => 'economics','category_id' => 4],
    ]);
```

I have no idea how to do it with `laravel-mongodb`,any suggestions?

Comment: do you have to give each entry a different foreign key?

Comment: @Sletheren I will import them into mysql,manipulating them in mongodb first.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$last_new_id = 1;

foreach($categories as $category){
    $category->id = $last_new_id ;
    $last_new_id++;
}

foreach($books as $book){
    $book->category_id = $categories->where('category',$book->category)->first()->id
}
```